# Date format to MM.DD.YYYY

Tags: apex, date

I'm trying to convert my datetime value into MM.DD.YYYY format

Tried the following,

```
1. 
datetime dt = system.today();

string f = DateTime.newInstance(
        dt.year(), dt.month(), dt.day()
    ).format('MM.DD.YYYY');
system.debug(f);
==> result: 05.133.2020 , expected result: 05.13.2020


2. 
datetime dt = system.today();
system.debug('d:'+dt.format('MM.DD.YYYY'));
==> result: 05.133.2020 , expected result: 05.13.2020
```

I know I could something like the following,

```
datetime d = system.today();
string s = d.month()+ '.' + d.day() + '.' + d.year();
system.debug(s);
```

But want to see why the format method is not working.

Please let me know what did I miss here?

Comment: `.format('MM.dd.YYYY')` with `DD` you are asking for the day of the year, which is `133`. Salesforce uses the format from Java

Comment: thanks for the answer. It worked. does the letter case matter in format method?

Comment: I think you would like to use also `yyyy` instead. that gives you the year and not the week year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)

> **format(dateFormatString)**
>
> Converts the date to the local time zone and
>   returns the converted date as a string using the supplied *Java simple
>   date format*. If the time zone cannot be determined, GMT is used.
>
> ...
>
> Usage
>
> For more information on the Java simple date format, see Java
>   [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

According to that link

> D: Day in year
>
> d: Day in month
>
> y: Year
>
> Y: Week year

So your format should be

```
.format('MM.dd.yyyy');
```